# Form action not redirecting on submit

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

I have an interesting situation as I am making an HTML form outputting directly to a Google Sheet (more info here: https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets). However, my form action will not redirect as the page simply stays the same when the submit button is clicked. The Google Sheet records the input, but not indication is made on the webpage. I would like to redirect to a completely different page.

I've noticed this is a common question, but all other answers either a) redirect and don't submit the user's response or b) submit the response but with no redirect.

Thanks in advance.

```js
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyoQPDaaR1YTUFjkU7weJ_Y9uCTE7hoOK_5yUQVjE8EjVuEIRBh/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>

<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" action="https://www.google.com">
  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="insert text">
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, how about this modification? If the event can be canceled, `preventDefault()` is used for canceling the event. In your situation, I would like to propose 2 patterns.

### Simple pattern:

As a simple modification, how about removing `e.preventDefault()`?

#### From:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

#### To:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message));
})
```

### Other pattern:

As other pattern, if you want to redirect only when `fetch()` returns no error, how about the following modification? In this case, `action="https://www.google.com"` of `<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" action="https://www.google.com">` is not used.

#### Sample script:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Success!', response);
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message));
});
```

### Reference:

- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

If these were not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @charleshawk Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.